# Facing error related to adding header and footer in node

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to add header and footer ejs file to my /views ejs tempelates but it is showing error
ReferenceError: E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\views\add.ejs:1

```
<% include /partials/header %> 


<h2>Hey,Ready to add a new and cool refreshmemt Hill Station</h2>
```

```
partials is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:661:12), <anonymous>:8:17)
    at add (E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:691:17)
    at tryHandleCache (E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\hillstation.js:18:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Web Dev\Hill Station\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The syntax has changed

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

and I guess you are using **ejs**

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

for more [refer ejs Documention](https://ejs.co/)

Comment: no i have included ejs. ya I was using old syntax. Thanks bro

Comment: if it helped you, please accept this as a solution to your question so that it will help others in the future.